How to create a .Net API from Open API specifications
I am working in an API first organisation and have received an OpenAPI .yaml specification for an API I need to create from a service called Stoplight (https://stoplight.io/).
What is the easiest way of creating a .Net (8) API from these files? Can I generate a interface I can implement or what is the prefeered way?
I mean I could hand-write it but thats going to contain mistakes, there must be some way to generete the C# code from these files right?
I've tried to search for this but everything I have found is the other way around, that you generate specifications from the coded API.

The same company (Smartbear) has a server stub generator. NSwag also has a controller generator command. These aren't as useful as you assume though. An OpenAPI spec essentially describes the DTOs and endpoints, not how they work. You can generate the DTOs and commands but you still have to write the application, validation, authentication code. You can get the DTOs by generating a client from the spec too

In general, search for server stub, design first or contract first. There are various tools, but the quality of their code depends entirely on the templates they use.
